# Maslov class of a diagonal

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. Which condition on $M$ guarantees that the diagonal of $(M \times M, (\omega,-\omega))$ has a vanishing Maslov class? $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$ is enough, but I am looking for some less restrictive condition.